# Entity Framework Reverse Engineer using Power Tools - No Primary Keys

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, t4

I've used the Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 2 to reverse engineer my model classes.
However no primary keys have been declared in the data annotations.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the mapping done via fluent.

If you want to change that, you can customize the TT files used to generate the model. Where you would remove it from the mapping.tt and then add the data annotation to entity.tt.  [Rowan Miller made a great post](http://romiller.com/2012/05/09/customizing-reverse-engineer-code-first-in-the-ef-power-tools/) about that.

Comment: When you say the mapping is done via Fluent - is this in the folder that is created by the reverse engineering entitled Mapping?

Comment: Yes - it creates a mapping file for each of your entities, in the Mapping folder, and then uses the fluent to declare everything.

Comment: OK Suddenly many things just clicked into place.  
Presumably then I want to map controllers to the Mappings Classes rather than the POCO's?

Comment: No, your controllers should still point to the pocos, the mapping is just telling EF how your pocos lay out in the database.

Comment: If I attempt to create a controller to the POCO it fails because the POCO has no key defined?

Comment: Can you create a new question and post the code for your controller?