# Unable to retrieve metadata for model. One or more Validation errors were detected during model generation: table has no key defined

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

Following on from this question here:[Entity Framework Reverse Engineer using Power Tools - No Primary Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110569/entity-framework-reverse-engineer-using-power-tools-no-primary-keys/12110996#comment16192765_12110996)

I've reverse engineered a database using Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 2.
This has created a large number of POCO's and a mappings folder with the entity mappings.

When I attempt to create a controller using the Add Controller Dialog I get the following message box come up:

Unable to retrieve metadata for *cruise model*.  One or more Validation errors were detected during model generation: 
\tSystem.Data.Entity.EmdEntityTypes:: *cruise table* has no key defined.  Define the key for this EntityType.

This repeats many times for all the related tables to the original one for which I was trying to create a controller.

The Controller itself is never created and on pressing OK I'm returned to the Add Controller Dialog.

The model in question definitley has a primary key defined in it's mapping file:

// Primary Key
this.HasKey(t => t.cruise_ID);

What am I doing wrong?

How does the controller find the mapping classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been able to replicate the error your receive, and it's related to trying to create a controller for the Model itself, rather than for the entity type.

The MVC scaffolding is designed to target an entity, then the related context - are you sure you're selecting the right items in the drop down?

[image]

In This image:

- Your model drop down (Mine shows A (MVCExamples.Models)) should refer to what I assume is your cruise entity.
- Your Data Context should be the DbContext that gets created (Mine shows Entities (MVCExamples.Models))

Comment: Thanks that's got it.  I didn't realise the reverse engineering would create the context as well.  As a result I'd started creating my own which of course didn't include the mappings.

Answer (score 2):

ADD :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

and a primary key to db class is calling'